# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: -- can I be certain that this is run on the main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, thread-safety

I am using iOS and I want to run an import process on the main thread while showing a progress hud. I thought I should use performSelectorOnMainThread, but that does not offer the 'withDelay' parameter. Can I be sure, if I am currently on the main thread, that the following code will be performed on the main thread?

```
- (void)tkContactsMultiPickerController:(TKContactsMultiPickerController *)picker didFinishPickingDataWithInfo:(NSArray *)contacts
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;

    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:[self importingString] maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];

    [self performSelector:@selector(importContacts:) withObject:contacts afterDelay:.1];
}
```

Comment: Your wording is unclear. If `tkContactsMultiPickerController:` is called on the main thread then yes, `importContacts:` will also be called on the main thread.

Comment: Yes, tkContactsMultiPickerController is called on the main thread. I will attempt to reword the question.

Comment: I actually did originally have some question as to whether or not I was on the main thread since I used dispatch_async to access the address book, but I did log using [NSThread isMainThread] throughout the code to verify that I was on the main thread and that using the performSelector method as above did, in fact, keep me on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:) says this explicitly:

> Invokes a method of the receiver on the current thread using the default mode after a delay.

You can also use `dispatch_after()` if you need to get back to the main thread from another -- tasks on the main queue [are guaranteed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW15) to be run on the main thread.